# Update values in column based on values in another table using an existing table as reference

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a manager_details table with team_id being NULL.
I have another table Team_details where the team id and manager id are populated.
I want to, update the manager_details.Team_id with the values of team_details.team_id values based on the manager_id values.

This is manager_details table :

| Manger_id | Manager_name | Team_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1009 | Edward | Null |
| 1101 | Gori | Null |
| 1002 | Shiv | Null |

This is Team_details table :

| Team_id | Team_name | manager_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | NOAM | 1101 |
| 101 | EMEA | 1009 |
| 102 | APGC | 1002 |

Then final output of the Mananger_details should be something like this:

| Manger_id | Manager_name | Team_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1009 | Edward | 101 |
| 1101 | Gori | 101 |
| 1002 | Shiv | 102 |

I have tried the queries :

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Manager_details (team_id)
SELECT Team_details.Team_id
from [dbo].[Team_details]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Manager_details]
on Team_details.team_id =  Manager_details.team_id
where manager_details.team_ID is null
```

The result I get is "0 rows affected".
Thanks to @larnu's comment, I figured that as the manager_details.team_id is NULL, the insert into was not working.
The solution that worked for me is below :

```
UPDATE dbo.Manager_details
SET manager_details.team_id = team_details.[Team_id]
FROM dbo.team_details
where Team_details.Manager_id= Manager_details.Manager_id
```

Comment: `manager_details.team_ID = null` can **never** be true. When comparing the `NULL` values you *need* to use `IS (NOT) NULL` (or in 2022+ you also have `IS (NOT) DISTINCT FROM`)

Comment: @larnu thanks for the insights. What worked for me is this : 
`UPDATE dbo.Manager_details
SET manager_details.team_id = team_details.[Team_id]
FROM dbo.team_details
where Team_details.Manager_id= Manager_details.Manager_id`